# Move all rows in a tsv with a certain date to their own file

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have a TSV file with 4 columns in this format

```
dog    phil    tall    2020-12-09 12:34:22
cat    jill    tall    2020-12-10 11:34:22
```

The 4th column is a date string Example :  `2020-12-09 12:34:22`

I want every row with the same date to go into its own file

For example,

file `20201209` should have all rows that start with `2020-12-09` in the 4th column
file `20201210` should have all rows that start with `2020-12-10` in the 4th column

Is there any way to do this through the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk to allow potentially large numbers of concurrently open output files and `gensub()`:

```
awk '{print > gensub(/-/,"","g",$(NF-1))}' file
```

With any awk:

```
awk '{out=$(NF-1); gsub(/-/,"",out); if (seen[out]++) print >> out; else print > out; close(out)}' file
```

There's ways to speed up either script by sorting the input first if that's an issue.

Comment: wow! thanks for that. Going through the command, I'm having a little trouble understanding what each part does. I'd appreciate if you could break that code down even though it works great for my understanding.

In particular, what does the ```if (seen[out]++) print >> out; else print > out; close(out)}``` do?

Comment: if the output file is being written to for the first time use the `>` construct to overwrite anything that was in it if it previously existed, subsequent times use `>>` to append to it.